# How can I check if the value in datagridview1 is equal or less than the value in listview1

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datagridview, ms-access-2010

I have a `Datagridview1` and a `Listview1` when clicked on datagridview it transfer the data to textbox and after it I input the quantity of an item.
When save is pressed it is saved in database (ms Access).

If the item in datagridview is less than or equal it does not make an error. But if I click the item again it will ask for the same quantity.

What I want to do is check if the item in `listview1` and in `textbox(quantity)` is show me a messagebox that if `listview1.subitem` + `textbox(quantity)` less than the item on `datagridview1`.

this is my dataGridView3 load event

```
public void dgvData()
{
   try
   {
       con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
       con.Open();
       String sql = "SELECT StockID,Menu.MenuID,MenuName,Price,sum(Quantity) from Stocks,Menu where Stocks.MenuID=Menu.MenuId group by StockID,MenuName,Price,Menu.MenuID having sum(quantity > 0) order by MenuName";
       cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
       dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
       dataGridView3.Rows.Clear();
       while (dr.Read() == true)
       {
          dataGridView3.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4]);
       }
       con.Close();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }
}
```

this is dataGridView3 Click Event

```
private void dataGridView3_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
       try
       {
          btnAddCart.Enabled = true;
          txtQtyKilo.Enabled = true;
          txtTotalPayment.Enabled = true;
          AcceptButton = btnAddCart;
          ErrorMenuName.Clear();
          DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView3.SelectedRows[0];
          txtMenuID.Text = dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
          txtMenuName.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
          txtUnitPrice.Text = dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
          txtOnHand.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
          txtQtyKilo.Focus();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

and lastly my button to insert data on ListView1

```
private void AddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView3.ClearSelection();
            try
            {
                if (txtClientID.Text == "")
                {
                    ErrorClientID.SetError(txtClientID, "Select A Client!");
                    return;
                }
                if (txtMenuName.Text == "")
                {
                    ErrorMenuName.SetError(txtMenuName, "Select Menu!");
                    return;
                }
                if (txtQtyKilo.Text == "")
                {
                    ErrorQtyPerKilo.SetError(txtQtyKilo, "Enter No. of Quantity Per Kilo!");
                    txtQtyKilo.Focus();
                    return;
                }
                int SaleQty = Convert.ToInt32(txtQtyKilo.Text);
                if (SaleQty == 0)
                {
                    ErrorQtyPerKilo.SetError(txtQtyKilo, "Input Must Be Greater Than 0");
                    txtQtyKilo.Focus();
                    return;
                }
                txtQtyKilo.Enabled = false;
                btnSave.Enabled = true;
                if (ListView1.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem();
                    lst.SubItems.Add(txtMenuID.Text);
                    lst.SubItems.Add(txtMenuName.Text);
                    lst.SubItems.Add(txtUnitPrice.Text);
                    lst.SubItems.Add(txtQtyKilo.Text);
                    lst.SubItems.Add(txtTotalAmount.Text);
                    ListView1.Items.Add(lst);
                    txtSubTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
                    txtST.Text = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(txtSubTotal.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxPer.Text) / 100)).ToString();
                    txtGrandTotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtSubTotal.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtST.Text)).ToString();
                    int val1 = 0;
                    int val2 = 0;
                    int.TryParse(txtGrandTotal.Text, out val1);
                    int.TryParse(txtTotalPayment.Text, out val2);
                    int I = (val1 - val2);
                    txtPaymentDue.Text = I.ToString();
                    texboxClear();
                    return;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text == txtMenuID.Text)
                    {
                        ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[1].Text = txtMenuID.Text;
                        ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text = txtMenuName.Text;
                        ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[3].Text = txtUnitPrice.Text;
                        ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[4].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[4].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtQtyKilo.Text)).ToString();
                        ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[5].Text = (Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[j].SubItems[5].Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtTotalAmount.Text)).ToString();
                        txtSubTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
                        txtST.Text = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(txtSubTotal.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxPer.Text) / 100)).ToString();
                        txtGrandTotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtSubTotal.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtST.Text)).ToString();
                        int val1 = 0;
                        int val2 = 0;
                        int.TryParse(txtGrandTotal.Text, out val1);
                        int.TryParse(txtTotalPayment.Text, out val2);
                        int I = (val1 - val2);
                        txtPaymentDue.Text = I.ToString();
                        texboxClear();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                ListViewItem lst1 = new ListViewItem();
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtMenuID.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtMenuName.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtUnitPrice.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtQtyKilo.Text);
                lst1.SubItems.Add(txtTotalAmount.Text);
                ListView1.Items.Add(lst1);
                txtSubTotal.Text = subtot().ToString();
                txtST.Text = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToInt32(txtSubTotal.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxPer.Text) / 100)).ToString();
                txtGrandTotal.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtSubTotal.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(txtST.Text)).ToString();
                int val3 = 0;
                int val4 = 0;
                int.TryParse(txtGrandTotal.Text, out val3);
                int.TryParse(txtTotalPayment.Text, out val4);
                int I1 = (val3 - val4);
                txtPaymentDue.Text = I1.ToString();
                texboxClear();
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

this is my only validation on datagridview.

```
 private void txtSaleQty_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            int val1 = 0;
            int val2 = 0;
            int.TryParse(txtOnHand.Text, out val1);
            int.TryParse(txtQtyKilo.Text, out val2);
            if (val2 > val1)
            {
                ErrorQtyPerKilo.SetError(txtQtyKilo, "Select Available Quantity or < Quantity");
                txtQtyKilo.Text = "";
                txtTotalAmount.Text = "";
                txtQtyKilo.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorQtyPerKilo.Clear();
            }
        }
```

it just check if the quantity on onhand.text is less than the inputted quantity.

Comment: That it is greater than the quantity in hand.

Comment: so what u need a sql query or a validation ?

Comment: then we need asp.net markup and also at what point do u want to trigger this validation ?

Comment: if quantity on listbox and textbox is greater than the quantity on datagridview

Comment: you are telling about all the quanityt of the datagridview ? or a particular row value ?

Comment: particular row ofc. should be quantity on  listview.subitem + textbox.text is less than  the quantity on datagridview.

Comment: at what event you would check the validation in row command ?

Comment: upon adding in listview.

Comment: not clear , need more code and what you have tried !!

Comment: this is what my form1 do. When cell click on datagridview the value is transferred in textbox.set textbox quantity to 1,after clicking 'add to cart button' it transfer to listview and clear the textboxes. then i get the item again on datagridview set quantity of textbox to 100. 
when i press add to cart it should show me a messagebox that says the quantity is greater than the quantity on hand. because the quantity on datagridview is 100 and i am adding up the quantity in listview to 101.

Comment: @Webruster i cant post an image it said required 10 reputation.

Comment: got your point .. now you need to know the ssum of the values in List box and just add it to the text box value  and keep this sum(listbox total sum + textbox value ) to a variable and compare it with the value coming from datagrid on add to cart click event. if you want i can provide you to get the sum of the values of listview

Comment: yes, appreciate that.

Comment: is it fine if i give the serverside for listbox sum of values or do you need client side ?

Comment: go to asp markup and add the rowdatabound and try that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed here is the code to get the total sum of listview values of a column i.e. `Quantity`  add these to the `Textbox` value and compare with the value coming from the `datagridview` value .

```
  double totl = 0;



protected void lvtest_DataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)

{

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)

    {

        Label lbltotalquantity= e.Item.FindControl("lblquantity") as Label;

        totl += Convert.ToDouble(lbltotalquantity.Text);

    }

}



protected void lvtest_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    Label lblTot = this.lvProducts.FindControl("lblTotal") as Label;

    lblTot.Text = totl.ToString(); ;

}
```

**EDIT :**

```
 // Optional ToDo: pass a int value indicating which "column" to add up
    public decimal GetSubTotal()
    {

        decimal TotalValue = default(decimal);
        decimal tmp = default(decimal);

        // arrays and collections start at index(0) not (1)


        for (int n = 0; n <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; n++)
        {
            // ToDo: Not all items must have the same number of SubItems
            // should also check SubItems Count >= 1 for each item
            // try to get the value:
            if (decimal.TryParse(ListView1.Items(n).SubItems(1).Text, tmp))
            {
                TotalValue += tmp;
            }
        }

        return TotalValue;
    }
```

**Updated Answer**

```
int num1 = 0; int i = 0; int j = 0; int h = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; k++)
{
  i = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[k].SubItems[4].Text);  
}

int.TryParse(txtQtyKilo.Text, out j); 
num1 = i + j;
textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);
int.TryParse(textBox11.Text, out h);
if (num1 <= Convert.ToInt32(txtOnHand.Text))
{
  textBox11.Text = "";
}
else
{
  txtQtyKilo.Text = "";
  textBox11.Text = "";
  MessageBox.Show("Must not be greater than the available menu!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88611/discussion-on-answer-by-webruster-how-can-i-check-if-the-value-in-datagridview1).

Answer (score -1):

this is the code:

```
int num1 = 0; int i = 0; int j = 0; int h = 0;
for (int k = 0; k <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; k++)
{
  i = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[k].SubItems[4].Text);  
}

int.TryParse(txtQtyKilo.Text, out j); 
num1 = i + j;
textBox11.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);
int.TryParse(textBox11.Text, out h);
if (num1 <= Convert.ToInt32(txtOnHand.Text))
{
  textBox11.Text = "";
}
else
{
  txtQtyKilo.Text = "";
  textBox11.Text = "";
  MessageBox.Show("Must not be greater than the available menu!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

but still error occur on

`i = Convert.ToInt32(ListView1.Items[k].SubItems[4].Text);`

if I input a quantity of 10/100 and on my next input I input 100/100

`MessageBox.Show("Must not be greater than the available menu!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);`

shows. but if i input 90/100 on my second quantity input it save sucessfully. what do I do to prevent this?

Comment: might be someother issue in the code .. its a seperate issue .. raise a different quest

Comment: @anjonnette  This answer was also proposed by me right ?